# Does the ratio of two non-convergent functions always approach $0$ as their arguments grow large but the numerator's derivative is less?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am wondering if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {P(x)} {Q(x)}$ always is $0$ where neither $P$ or $Q$ converge in the limit, and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} Q'(x)>P'(x)$. How can we show this? It seems intuitively clear on some level but I feel I may be making an oversight.

Edit: As a followup question, what about when $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are different asymptotic [orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (where we disregard constants and lower order terms)? Does this ration approach 0), and the order of growth for $P(x)$ is smaller than the order of growth for $Q(x)$?

Comment: How does it "seem intuitively clear on some level"? A counterexample is $\frac x{2x}.$

Comment: @anneBauval I added a followup question about orders of growth; would you be able to take a look at it?

Comment: Your  *new* question is: does $\lim_{+\infty}\frac{P'}{Q'}=0$ imply $\lim_{+\infty}\frac PQ=0,$ provided $P,Q$ do not "converge in the limit"? If $\lim_{+\infty}|Q|= +\infty,$ [L'Hospital's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) answers you. Else (if $Q$ oscillates), there must exist counterexamples. Is that your ultimate question? If so, please update your post. (And the old questions should be suppressed or at least clearly mentionned as solved whence obsolete.) Also, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Answer (score 0):

It's false. Consider $P(x)=e^{2x}+x$ and $Q(x)=e^{x}$. Neither of these converge for $x\to\infty$, and $P'(x)=2e^{2x}+1>e^x=Q'(x)$.

But $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{e^{2x}+x}{e^x}=e^x+xe^{-x}$, which does not converge to $0$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Imo this question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. There was an obvious mistake in the question. Now that it has been updated, I think you should delete your answer.